# Querying Facebook's location_post table for specific region

Tags: sql, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a query to the "location_post" table through FB's FQL.

"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/location_post/"

I'm interesting in my friend's location post.

With the following, it throws me an error and loading for a while(possibly because there're too many results)

```
        SELECT id, page_id FROM location_post
        WHERE author_uid IN
        (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

I'm really only interested in a particular region at a time, it's not like I can read all my friends' activities around the world at a time.
So, how can I use the "coords" to limit the query within a region.
coords is an

```
         Array ( [latitude] => 37.86564 [longitude] => -122.25061 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id, page_id FROM location_post WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, '37.86564', '-122.25061') < 10000
```

This will give you all posts within 10,000 meters of the location.

Comment: I'm very amazed it works so simply. I couldn't find it anywhere in the documentation. Is there any other hidden gems like this?